# Method for determining browser capabilities?

Tags: javascript

The JavaScript Navigator object type can be used to determine which web browser a user is running. This method for determining a web browser’s capabilities is no longer recommended. Is there a better method for determining browser capabilities?

Comment: How you detect support for a specific feature depends on that feature.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

Note: The recommended alternative to this property is NavigatorUAData.platform, which is returned from Navigator.userAgentData.
[source](https://docs.w3cub.com/dom/navigator/platform)

Comment: It still isn't recommended for determining the browser capabilities.

Comment: There is no alternative at this point and their is just warning. Warning !!!
The information from the navigator object can often be misleading, and should not be used to detect browser versions because:

Different browsers can use the same name
The navigator data can be changed by the browser owner
Some browsers misidentify themselves to bypass site tests
Browsers cannot report new operating systems, released later than the browser https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp

Comment: "There is no alternative at this point" — There is: Feature detection. It's been the recommended approach since the '90s.

Comment: you can try this API, but it does not have 100% accuracy on all capabilities https://featurejs.com/

Comment: Feature detection is only available from Navigator

Comment: That's nonsense. The specifics of how to detect a feature depend on which feature you want to detect, but they generally don't involve interacting with the Navigator API.

Comment: For those features available outside navigator, you can use featurejs.com

Comment: Maybe. It depends on what feature the OP wants to detect. We don't know what that is.

Comment: @Quentin please upvote my answer , I have explained it in my comment

Comment: It's a bad answer to a bad question.

Comment: I think the question was ok and the answer was meaningful, but you just want to downgrade my tries

Comment: The question was looking for an alternative to Navigator as a means to detect specific but unspecified features. Your answer recommended using a specific bit of the Navigator object which only provided the platform (which has practically no clues about the features the browser supports). It is an awful, useless answer that just wastes peoples time.